# TS error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using lodash on a TypeScript app and I am getting an error

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: never, index: number, array: never[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | ((callbackfn: (value: Phone, index: number, array: Phone[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)

Function:

```
        {get(userInfo, 'phone', []).map((item, index) => (
          <View style={styles.userPhone} key={index}>
            {item.type === 'Desk' && <Text>Phone: {item.num}</Text>}
            {item.type === 'Mobile' && <Text>Mobile: {item.num}</Text>}
          </View>
        ))}
```

If I do this it works correctly:

```
        {userInfo.phone &&
           userInfo.phone.map((item, index) => (
            <View style={styles.userPhone} key={index}>
              {item.type === 'Desk' && <Text>Phone: {item.num}</Text>}
              {item.type === 'Mobile' && <Text>Mobile: {item.num}</Text>}
            </View>
        ))}
```

So what could I be missing?

PS:
Lodash `get` docs: https://lodash.com/docs/#get

I have installed types package for lodash -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

The thing is that I can not do it like this `{userInfo.phone && userInfo.phone.map(...)}` because we are enforced to use `get` for this type of things.

Comment: Please consider editing this code to be a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Ideally the code would have no external dependencies and could demonstrate your issue in a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: Without such a reproducible example, I can only really guess what will fix your issue because I can't test it. My guess: `get(userInfo, 'phone', [] as Phone[])` or `const noPhones: Phone[] = []; get(userInfo, 'phone', noPhones)`

Comment: Hi @jcalz put it as an answer so I can give you the proper vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I don't have lodash typings available, I'll just assume that the `get()` function behaves more or less as follows:

```
type ReplaceUndefined<T, V> = T extends undefined ? V : T;

declare function get<T, K extends keyof T, V>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  dflt: V
): ReplaceUndefined<T[K], V>;
```

This means that if `key` of type `K` is a key of `obj` of type `T`, then `get()` will return a value of type `T[K]`... unless that value may be `undefined`, in which case it will replace `undefined` with the type of the `dflt` value, like this:

```
const val = get({ a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : undefined }, "a", 123); // string | number
```

Also, I'm asssuming the following type and value declarations:

```
interface Phone {
  type: string;
  num: string;
}
declare const userInfo: { phone?: Phone[] };
```

---

Now I'm ready to start answering the question.  When I try to call `get()` like this, we get an error:

```
get(userInfo, "phone", []).map((item, index) => "Number: " + item.num); // error!
// "cannot invoke an expression that lacks a call signature"
```

The problem is that the default value `[]` is inferred by the compiler to be of type `never[]`.  This the return value of `get()` will be the union type `Phone[] | never[]`, and thus the `map` method of this union will itself be a union of the method types for `Phone[]` and for `never[]`.  It is a longstanding issue in TypeScript that [you usually can't call unions of functions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).  This has been [improved](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) in recent language versions, but there are still [limitations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#caveats-2), such as when more than one function in the union is generic.  And since `map()` is generic, TypeScript doesn't know how to call it on `Phone[] | never[]`.

---

The obvious fix here is that you don't want `[]` to be treated as `never[]`; instead you'd like it to be treated as an empty `Phone[]`.  If you can do that, then what comes out of `get()` will be `Phone[] | Phone[]`, which is just `Phone[]`, and therefore its `map()` method is no longer a union type, and is callable.

Here are two ways to do it... one is with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
get(userInfo, "phone", [] as Phone[]).map((item, index) => "Number: " + item.num); // okay
```

and the other is with a type annotation on a new variable:

```
const noPhones: Phone[] = [];
get(userInfo, "phone", noPhones).map((item, index) => "Number: " + item.num); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCBVAdgEwgMwEtMJsAeAFQBooA1APigF4pyoIAPYCHAZygFcc+IiSgB+WlABcLANwBYAFBLcKZACdoeQSmAEA9pigBzCMArUA0m07dsfANYQQ+vC2r0AFEqhR9AIwArGSofKCcQGUtKMOw8BGAZGiUAShk4RFQMIUJiMnIAbUsAXQ86BWVFFEMeYCgANyQEJhMzTwBvKCQZAFkkYAALADp1JBx9AFtPFKhSKAAGIYBWcSgAIiQ16QEckWwoAF9qDbXqAEYAJgBmFNkoAHp7qFr1ImMoAB8oTH4J-wh1EolEQuOo8FkoAAFAaGaDtMKgSAyF5vCq+H4TZHAV6YYwVA4qCBqJCaKDVTC1AQ8AEASUweH0Mk6YBhxDEMmhsIKxUOFSUpmAnn41PUdIZxxZsNOUG5KSGEyQYE8ngIXAm1CIuHYM0YDDWADlfv91DItgBqKCqiATIYY24PJ4A9T6dQAQiUj3WKDGmH0dSI9X0Ti6Rg4YE0PB4BiMg36UGQKAcfCQZKazSjxkw-X4mjWQMUAqFIrF+glrIg0u5XT4nOIsvliu8il8KrVGqE2qYesNfwBpqgFqtNoxqT5VRqdV9tYgPA55arzG5FULwtp9NL60lxGlU-LPDlCqVret7a1Ou7Rr76wHlrVtt+tyUQA)